# SQL Substring REGEX pattern matching (TERADATA)

Tags: sql, regex, teradata

I have a column say `LINES` with the below string patters. I want to extract the date from the strings. For example for each lines I would need the date i.e `20201123` or `20201124` whichever the case may be.
Since the dates are in different positions I can't really use `substring` for this. How do I go about this ? Is there a simpler REGEX method within `substring` that I can apply to this.

Here is a simple reproduced code for testing.

```
create volatile table TEST
(LINES VARCHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

insert into TEST values('path/to/file/OVERALL_GOTO_Datas.20201123.dat');
insert into TEST values('path/to/file/endartstmov20201124.20201124.dat');
insert into TEST values('path/to/file/TESTDEV20201123.20201123.5.0014.CHK.dat');
insert into TEST values('path/to/file/DEVTOTES20201124.20201124.5.0109.CHK.dat');
insert into TEST values('path/to/file/STORE_PARTNER.20201124.20201124.0.0501.CHK.dat');

SELECT * FROM TEST;
```

Appreciate your responses. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [teradata `REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/bSkgRmSt8P48II0SKyyH3Q)

You should be able to use this regex :

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(LINES, '(:?\.([0-9]{8})\.)')
```

see : https://regex101.com/r/WRqEmY/2

---

An other way is with `regexp_extract` ( https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/148t/functions/regexp.html )

```
SELECT regexp_extract(LINES, '(?:\.([0-9]{8})\.)', 1)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. That works pretty much well. `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(LINES, '(:?\.([0-9]{8})\.)')` .

Comment: @der_radler you could try this : `SELECT regexp_extract('LINES, '(?:\.([0-9]{8})\.)', 1)` It should give you just the date without the two `.`.

Comment: Using Lookahead/Lookbehind to get the date only: `'(?<=\.)([0-9]{8})(?=\.)`

Comment: Thanks. Can you point out to a good explanation to this regex formulation. Would be great to learn this stuff.

Comment: https://www.rexegg.com has detailed info on RegExes and https://regex101.com/ can be used to test/verify them. Teradata is supports PCRE syntax.

Comment: @dnoeth I'm not found of lookahead/behind regex : it's usually heavy on the regex engine, but it's an other way to do it, yes.

Comment: @Blag: There's no `regexp_extract` in Teradata (the link is from Presto docu), but `trim(both '.' from col)` could be used. Or an undocumented variation of regexp_substring: `RegExp_Substr_gpl(LINES, '\.([0-9]{8}).', 1, 1, '', 1)`